# Play Framework 2.0 form helper: from select to List<T>

Tags: java, forms, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a model that contains a ManyToMany relation:

```
@JoinTable(name = "Contract_has_Institution", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "contract_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "institution_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
@ManyToMany
public List<Institution> institutionCollection;
```

In the scala.html i have two select, to add two elements in the list (two Insitutions)

```
    @select(contractForm("institutionCollection"),
         options = options(InstitutionController.options),
         '_default -> "--- Choose an institution ---",
         '_label -> "Institution A",
         '_showConstraints -> false)

    @select(contractForm("institutionCollection"),
         options = options(InstitutionController.options),
         '_default -> "--- Choose an institution ---",
         '_label -> "Institution B",
         '_showConstraints -> false)
```

I've tried adding [] to the fields like this

```
 contractForm("institutionCollection[]"),
```

but it doesn't work.
How can I bind the two selected choices to the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view, if you use your current code :

```scala
 @select(contractForm("institutionCollection"),
     options = options(InstitutionController.options),
     '_default -> "--- Choose an institution ---",
     '_label -> "Institution A",
     '_showConstraints -> false)

@select(contractForm("institutionCollection"),
     options = options(InstitutionController.options),
     '_default -> "--- Choose an institution ---",
     '_label -> "Institution B",
     '_showConstraints -> false)
```

So, you can get the value of your multiple select by using this code (this is only example):

```java
public static Result someAction() {
    Map<String,String[]> formData = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();

    Institution institution;
    // get all institutionCollection select value
    for (String insId : formData.get("institutionCollection")) {
        Logger.debug("INSTITUTION SELECTED = " + insId); // log info

        // I assume that select value is the ID of each Institution record
        institution = Institution.find.byId(Long.parseLong(insId))
        SomeModel.institutionCollection.add(institution) // add to the list to your model
    }
    SomeModel.save(); // save changes
    return ok("success");
}
```